# Centrally symmetric neighborly polytopes

Tags: discrete-geometry, convex-polytopes, convex-geometry

Let $P$ be a centrally symmetric [$k$-neighborly $d$-polytope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neighborly_polytope). Let $ P^* $ is polar (also dual) of $P$. Consider a polytope  $Q^*$ , $Q^* \subset P^* $(not necessarily a face of $P^*$). By duality,
 $P\subset Q $. How neighbourly is this $Q$? Is it $k$, or less than $k$, or more than $k$-neighborly?

Comment: This does not answer your question, but Grünbaum's book *Convex Polytopes* indicates (p.129b) that it is an open problem whether there exists any polytope other than a simplex that is 2-neighborly and its dual is 2-neighborly.

Comment: The question is not clear. What do you assume on Q? is it a convex hull of some vertices of P?